# Django filer thumbnail's path

Tags: django, django-filer, easy-thumbnails

I've created a custom User model based on AbstractUser model. How can I find the right path to my thumbnail to use in a template file ?

### models.py

```
class User(AbstractUser):
     photo = FilerImageField(related_name='profile_photo', null=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
```

### home.html

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% load thumbnail %}

{% block content %}

{% thumbnail user.photo 250x250 crop %}
          {% thumbnail user.photo 250x250 crop %} #
{% endblock %}
```

```
TemplateSyntaxError
Exception Value:    
Variable 'user.photo' is an invalid source.
```

Comment: try `user.photo.url`

Answer (score 0):

Try this one in template if you are using sorl-thumbnail

```
{% thumbnail user.photo "250x250" crop="center" as im %}
    <img src="{{ im.url }}" width="{{ im.width }}" height="{{ im.height }}">
{% endthumbnail %}
```

If you are using easy thumbnail use below code in template.html

```
{% load thumbnail %}
<img src="{% thumbnail profile.photo 50x50 crop %}" alt="" />
```

If you are using django-filer don't need to be in template thumbnail tag

```
{% load thumbnail %}
{% thumbnail user.photo 250x250 crop %}
```

Comment: {% thumbnail <model>.<image_field> 100x100 crop %} works well. My question was how to find the right source if my User model inherits from AbstractUser class ? In my case {% thumbnail user.photo 100x100 crop %} doesn't work

Comment: Try request.user.photo